# Power/current limitations of variable gain amplifier

Tags: amplifier, gain, variable

I am working with a motor invention and I am wondering about the utility of variable gain amplifiers. I wonder how to achieve a high output current with such an amplifier¿

Comment: Milliamps, milliwatts, usually. And any linear amplifier is hopelessly wasteful in power for driving a motor. Use switching techniques like PWM, much faster than the mechanical inertia of the motor.

Comment: You can use a variable gain amplifier that that turns into PWM.

Comment: I can find one that has a minimum of 1.1 amps... But don't know what the maximum is http://www.linear.com/product/LT1210

Comment: Here are some purportedly high power ones but max current doesn't seem to be supplied http://www.linear.com/parametric/high_output_current_amplifiers

Comment: 50V 5A is audio amplifier territory and lots of design examples out there.

Comment: Here is a discussion about the load handled by an opportunity amp https://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1272353

Comment: *I'll guess than frequency less than 1 kHz 48 volts 500 amps* OK, except for the current of 500A that could make it audio amplifier territory. You should consider making a scaled down prototype needing less current so that you can **prove the concept**. In a final product you would/should not be supplying 500A from a linear amplifier as that is insanely inefficient (power will be lost). It will have to be a switching (PWM) solution which is used for motors almost everywhere.

Comment: Yes thanks. My intent is to simulate first and then build a low power model. But I was wondering how extensible the approach is to large current applications

Answer (score 0):

*I wonder how much current could be achieved with such an amplifier?*

That depends on many things:

- what voltage is needed?
- What kind of signal will you amplify, what frequency content? What will create that signal?
- you say "low power" but that doesn't mean anything, is that 1 mW, 1 W or 1 kW?
- What is a "very large motor"? How large is large?
- What amount of power does the motor need?
- What is the budget for making this device if you cannot buy it?

Comment: Picture the motor application being for a motor driving Tesla's cars

Comment: Hmm, I'm not involved in the drive electronics for electric cars **at all** so I can still only **guess**. Which I'm not going to do.

Comment: I'll guess than frequency less than 1 kHz 48 volts 500 amps.

Comment: @JordanMcBain Great information, that should be edited into your question.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the resolution to my concern although not specifically addressed in the question (I am not an EE)

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/how-to-buffer-an-op-amp-output-for-higher-current-part-1/

The answer being to buffer the op amps output as described in this webpage.

Comment: You should **Edit** your question and add this information to your question. Then **delete** this "answer" because, is it an answer? No it is not.

Comment: But as has been suggested there is more to the story https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/5590